# Buscar elemento por parte do código

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Tenho uma tabela com várias linhas e em uma coluna x tenho um href contendo o que preciso clicar, porém neste href só é colocado um gif e por isso não consigo capturar pelo PartialLinkText.

Existe alguma forma onde eu possa buscar o elemento por parte do código fonte?

Ex do link do href: 
`<a href="conteudo.cfm?ano=2019&amp;mes=8&amp;pid=3974&amp;mobi=1924817">`

Sendo que gostaria de procurar o elemento procurando pelo pedaço: `ano=2019&mes=8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar o seletor `element[atributo*=valor]`, ele vai procurar em qualquer parte, exemplo:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;

...

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(getDelay));

var elemento = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("a[href*='ano=2019&mes=8']")));

...
```

Se quiser passar valores "mais dinamicos" faça:

```
var ano = "2019";
var mes = "8";

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(getDelay));

var seletor = String.Format("a[href*='ano={0}&mes={1}']", ano, mes);

var elemento = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector(seletor)));
```

Note que usei `WebDriverWait`, que se chama espera explicita, ele espera o tempo até o element existir, se encontrar antes ele não precisa esperar o tempo todo, é muito melhor que `Thread.Sleep` para o **caso especifico**

Também usei `ElementIsVisible`, porque a condição é que tem que estar visível, mas se procura outros estados de elemento, segue a lista (documentação https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm):

- `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By)`

  Espera para verificar se um elemento está presente no DOM de uma página e visível. Visibilidade significa que o elemento não é apenas exibido, mas também possui uma altura e largura maiores que 0.
- `ExpectedConditions.ElementSelectionStateToBe(By, Boolean)`

  Espera para verificar se o elemento fornecido está no estado correto.
- `ExpectedConditions.ElementSelectionStateToBe(IWebElement, Boolean)`

  Espera para verificar se o elemento fornecido está no estado correto.
- `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By)`

  Espera para verificar um elemento é visível e ativada para que você possa clicar nele.
- `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable (IWebElement)`

  Espera para verificar um elemento é visível e ativada para que você possa clicar nele.
- `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeSelected(By)`

  Espera para verificar se o elemento especificado está selecionado.
- `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeSelected(IWebElement)`

  Espera para verificar se o elemento especificado está selecionado.
- `ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeSelected(IWebElement, Boolean)`

  Espera para verificar se o elemento especificado está selecionado.

Comment: Guilherme, ele está caindo por timeout porque não encontra o elemento.
Tentei alterar a sintaxe, colocando * (asterisco) no final, após o = (igual) e ainda assim não encontrou o elemento.

Comment: @AlfredoJamil se não encontrou é porque não existe ou porque esta dentro de um IFRAME.

Comment: Perfeito Guilherme. Estava em outro iFrame.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: @AlfredoJamil se puder marque a resposta como correta